# SSRS Static fields in groups

Tags: matrix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2016

Good afternoon!
I have created a report with the wizard to create a matrix that is grouped and has drill down rows. I have added filters to the rows and columns and it works great!  I then copied that matrix and modified the filters, so I had two matrixes.

[image]

But what I really wanted was those two rows in the same matrix, just in different row groups.  So I added another group, using the adjacent below option, and then added all the child groupings.  However, when I run the report it shows the values for the first row of the drill down data. 
[image]

When I look at the groupings I can see the one I did manually has a 'Static' field in each row grouping but the ones that the wizard did (with the red ?), they don't have that "extra" row:

[image]

What do I need to change or how do I need to add my groups so that I don't get that "static" row and not show the data?  I have the visibility set to 'Hidden' and the toggle set up for the prior grouping set data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a few things....

1. the data comes from a single dataset
2. You are differentiating between Property and Violent crimes by filtering on a column, I'll call it `IncidentGroup` for the sake of illustration..
3. I've understood your question ! :)

Get to the point where you had just a single tablix filtered to show 'Property crime'. 
Now remove or edit that filter so it shows all the data you need in the report.
Finally, right click on your `Matrix1_IncidentCategory` row and add a parent group, choose `IncidentGroup` (or whatever the column is actually called) and check the box to add a group header.
That should be it, there is no need for a second tablix.

Without knowing how you are filtering currently it's hard to give a complete answer but this should get you close, if not all the way there.

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, please post sample data from your dataset output and your current filters.

Comment: Thanks!  I am about to leave for the day but will try this first thing tomorrow.  yes, your assumptions are correct about having a single dataset with filtering on columns and rows based on ReportCategory and ReportSection (Violent/Property)

Comment: Thanks that did what I needed!